# Edit outgoing POST request payload from browser

Tags: google-chrome, http, post, firefox, networking

Is there a way to edit from my browser an outgoing POST request?
I have to edit the outgoing request before it's sent, I cannot send another POST request because the target site has the csrf protection to avoid duplicate requests.
I saw that [Requestly](https://requestly.io) has this feature but it's not included in the free plain.
I have no particular coding skill, a free application like this would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a HTTP(s) proxy. There are plenty of them, such as [Burp](https://portswigger.net/burp), [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/).